# rspec + capybara + factory_girl always creating test user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have an odd problem and I'm not sure how to debug it. I'm currently using these gems (which are the latest versions as of this post):

```
factory_girl-4.5.0
rspec-rails-3.1.0
capybara-2.4.4
guard-2.6.1
```

Whenever I start guard using `bundle exec guard` or whenever a new test runs, it always create a user in the test database. So that `User.count == 1` at every start. I can't figure out where that's called.

Here's my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'email_spec'
# require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'lorem-ipsum'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
  config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include ApplicationHelper
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Requests::JsonHelpers, :type => :request
  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    Mongoid::IdentityMap.clear  #If you have the identity map enabled in your application, you should set up a global hook to clear out the map before each test so the test suite does not create memory bloat. For example in RSpec in spec_helper.rb.
    Rails.cache.clear
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

and my `factories.rb` is pretty simple:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:authored_by]  do
    sequence(:first_name) {|n| "TestFN#{n}" }
    sequence(:last_name) {|n| "TestLN#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) {|n| "rspec-test-#{n}@example.com" }
  end
end
```

Any idea on where I should start debugging to figure out why the user is being created?

Comment: why it should not be created?

Comment: well try inserting the `pry` breakpoint to the factory `before` block

Answer (score 0):

Look in your /spec directory. Is FactoryGirl.lint being called? Are you calling the user factory in a test defined in spec/features, etc? Are you using DatabaseCleaner to maintain your test environment?